# PORT necessary for each FTP RETR

Tags: ftp

When downloading data over FTP, is it necessary to issue a PORT command before each RETR, or would it be legal to

```
PORT 165,82,22,48,133,72
RETR /1.txt
RETR /2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. (example is not legal)

```
< PORT 165,82,22,48,133,72
> RETR /1.txt
> RETR /2.txt
< 425 Use PORT or PASV first.
```